# No stash entries found. missing bucket_name

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, travis-ci, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy my Nodejs docker image on Aws Elastic beanstalk using Travis Ci but am getting an this error

```
  No stash entries found.
  missing bucket_name
  failed to deploy
```

My travis.yml has this but with my credentials

```
deploy:
  provider: elasticbeanstalk
  region: "us-east-1"
  app: "pool_auth_microservice"
  env: "<MY_AWS_ENV>"
  bucket_name: "<MY_BUCKET's BAME>"
  bucket_path: "<MY BUCKET_PATH>"
  on:
    branch: master

  access_key_id: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY
  secret_access_key: $AWS_SECRET_KEY
```

I have set the permissions policy to for I AM to fulla access. What might be the problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a known problem, i just added tis to the deploy section of my .travis.yml file and it worked

```
edge: true
```